Trying to find if an element is in a web page title
Im building a tool to check a list of Instagram username and tell if they are available. So for first underestand web scraping, i tried to check if "(" is in the title of the instagram page of @paris
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/paris/')
soup = BeautifulSoup ( url.content , "html.parser" )
title = soup.find('title')
print(title)
if '(' in title:
    print("Y")

So the page actually contain a ( inside is title but when i try the condition "if '(' in title" i doesn't print Y so it doesn't find the ( in "title"
Can anyone give me a way to make this code actually work, it's gonna be important for my project
(sorry for my bad english, im french)

title is an element. Use title.text to get its text content.

The reason it does not print "Y" is because the title is not a string in the way you are checking it. soup.find('title') returns a Tag object from BeautifulSoup, not just the text inside the  tag.
To fix this, you need to access the text inside the title tag correctly and then check if it contains the character '('.
title = soup.find('title')
title_text = title.text
print(title_text) 

if '(' in title_text: 
    print("Y")

